# Can't pretty print json from python

Tags: python, json

Whenever I try to print out json from python, it ignores line breaks and prints the literal string "\n" instead of new line characters.

I'm generating json using jinja2. Here's my code:

```
print json.dumps(template.render(**self.config['templates'][name]))
```

It prints out everything in the block below (literally - even the quotes and "\n" strings):

```
"{\n    \"AWSTemplateFormatVersion\" : \"2010-09-09\",\n    \"Description\" : ...
```

(truncated)

I get something like this whenever I try to dump anything but a dict. Even if I try json.loads() then dump it again I get garbage. It just strips out all line breaks.

What's going wrong?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is what I use for pretty-printing json-objects:

```
def get_pretty_print(json_object):
    return json.dumps(json_object, sort_keys=True, indent=4, separators=(',', ': '))

print get_pretty_print(my_json_obj)
```

`json.dumps()` also accepts parameters for encoding, if you need non-ascii support.

Comment: No this doesn't work. It doesn't address the problem with the fact that 'print' actually prints "\n" instead of new line characters.

Comment: It does work if use the JSON-_object_ (or rather the dict in python) as input for `json.dumps()`. If you already have a JSON-object represented as string, you don't need `json.dumps()` anymore.

Comment: if I run `dat = json.loads(payload.content)` where `type(payload)` is 
`<class 'requests.models.Response'>` and `type(dat)` is 
`<type 'dict'>`, `json.dumps(dat, indent=4)` still shows the `\n` characters in console output, and `json.dumps(payload.content, indent=4)` shows a slew of ` \\ ` characters and no indentation. Am I missing something here? EDIT: yes, looks like I had to do `print(json.dumps(dat, indent=4))` to get it to work in the interactive console session.

Answer (score 8):

`json.dumps()` returns a JSON-encoded string. The JSON standard mandates that newlines are encoded as `\\n`, which is then printed as `\n`:

```
>>> s="""hello
... there"""
>>> s
'hello\nthere'
>>> json.dumps(s)
'"hello\\nthere"'
>>> print(json.dumps(s))
"hello\nthere"
```

There's not much you can do to change that if you want to keep a valid JSON string. If you want to print it, the correct way would be to print the JSON *object*, not its string representation:

```
>>> print(s)
hello
there
>>> print(json.loads(json.dumps(s)))  # pointless; just for demonstration...
hello
there
```

Comment: I know. How do I make either json.dumps return new line characters instead of the literal, or how do I make print interpolate them instead of printing the literal?

Comment: @user1491250: You *haven't* printed it yet. If you had, the line breaks would be visible. You're having the Python shell display the return value, and that is done using the `repr` of the string.

Comment: updated. yes I have. the problem is that printing it prints the literal "\n" string instead of new lines. that's why i'm asking.

Comment: OK thanks. If I dump my json to a file and run it through `python -m json.tool` it comes out as I want. I'm trying to get my python script to return it like that. Do you know how I can replicate that output?

Comment: @user1491250: `json.loads()` the JSON-encoded string into an object, then `print` (or, perhaps even better, `pprint.pprint()`) that.

Answer (score 1):

The the problem is that your input to `json.dumps` is a `string`. Try the following:

```
print type(template.render(**self.config['templates'][name]))
```

It you are doing this to indent etc... try the following:

```
print json.dumps(json.loads(template.render(**self.config['templates'][name])), sort_keys=True, indent=4)
```

Answer (score 0):

If your string is already JSON then pretty print it using

```
def pp_json(json_string):
# converts json to dict then back to string... ridiculous but not pointless 
    print(json.dumps(json.loads(json_string), sort_keys=True, indent=4)) 
    return

pp_json(your_json_string)
```